# Create a dictionary with current_date as a key and value being how many times code run on that day Python

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary, for-loop

I need to create a list of dictionaries where key is `today's date` and the value is how many times the code run on `today's date`.

I created the for loop that does exactly what I need if I create the list of dictionaries with one key & value pair. As follows:

```
# Todays's date in variable
this_day_0 = date.today()

# Format the day to be like 20200420
this_day = this_day_0.strftime("%Y%m%d")

created_today = [{"20200419": 0]

for index, time_dict in enumerate(created_today):
    if this_day in time_dict.keys():
        time_dict[this_day] += 1
    else:
        time_dict[this_day] = 1
```

So if I ran it today, April 20th, the output would be this:

```
[{'20200419': 0, '20200420': 1}]
```

And if I ran the code one more time it would increment 20200420 value to 2. The question is how do I start with an empty list of `created_today` because in production the existing `created_today` list will be overwritten with the "20200419": 0 And I need to save the results on a daily basis. My desired output would be something like the following:

```
[{'20200419': 0, '20200420': 2, '20200421': 1, '20200422': 1}] and so forth
```

Comment: How about `logging` these events into a file and then evaluating the file when you need the results? Or a database? Because you'd have to write and read the state somewhere (file, database) between the runs.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is? Your logic seems to be correct. Are you asking how to keep it through different runs? If so, you can convert your dict to a JSON and save it to a file after your program ran. And obviously read the file and convert the JSON to a dict before the program runs and before incrementing it

Comment: @Sri Thank you for your response. I was just wondering if there is a way to do so without creating a file but seems like I'll have to do just that.

Comment: What you are showing in your example is a list with one single dictionary, not a list of dictionaries. Are you sure you don't need to append a new dict for each day? Your for loop will be iterating over one single item

Comment: I think you will need some external file. Or another program that is consistently running checking if another program has ran (but that would be much more tedious).

Comment: @Chique_Code essentially you need a form of *data persistence*, just using a file on local hard disk is the simplest thing. Note, using a list here doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I strongly suspect persistence is not the answer to your task. You need to rethink your logic completely. What you probably need is a while True loop that appends a new dict for each day, since the requirement, as you said, is to create a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `json` package for de/serializing the dictionary, and using files for persistence

```
import json
from datetime import date

try:
    with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read() or '{}'
    data = json.loads(contents)
except (FileNotFoundError, json.JSONDecodeError) as e:
    data = {}

key = date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
value = data.get(key, 0)
data[key] = value + 1

with open('file.json', 'w+') as f:
    print(json.dumps(data), file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pickle files to save a dictionary:

```
import pickle

this_day_0 = date.today()

this_day = this_day_0.strftime("%Y%m%d")

created_today = [{"20200419": 0}]

#load pickle to dictionary
with open('dict.pickle', 'rb') as dicto:
    created_today = pickle.load(dicto)

for index, time_dict in enumerate(created_today):
    if this_day in time_dict.keys():
        time_dict[this_day] += 1
    else:
        time_dict[this_day] = 1 

#save to pickle file
with open('dict.pickle', 'wb') as dicto:
    pickle.dump(created_today, dicto, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: For storing dictionaries like this I'd look at `PyYAML`. https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation